# Single words or compounds meaning "giving away of food" free of cost?

Tags: word-request

To distribute food items, especially cooked and  ready-to-eat, free of cost is a charity work. Is there any single word or an apt compound word or even a phrase for this distribution which involve a divine sanctity or charity sacredness. 
*Food distribution*, *food supply*, do not include the charity aspect.

Are "food offering" and "food handouts" good terms?
Any helpful suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: “Handouts” can include food, but note that the word has a [negative connotation](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/handout).

Answer (score 1):

The word you're thinking of is [**donate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/donate), and its variants:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *transitive*
>   *1* : to make a gift of
>   *especially* : to contribute to a public or charitable cause
>
> *intransitive*
>   : to make a donation
>
> // The computers were *donated* by local companies.
>   // We *donated* our old clothes to charity.

Gifts are given freely, and note the specific use of *charity* in the definition.

If you give away food for free, you are *donating* it to someone or some cause, and it would be considered a **food donation**.

Answer (score 0):

We have the word *alms*, defined as

> (in historical contexts) money or food given to poor people.

[[source](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/alms)]

The act of distributing this food or money is *giving alms* or *almsgiving*.

This word is most often used when the money or food is given for religious reasons (meaning, it has the implication of sanctity or sacredness you want). The Wikipedia article [Alms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alms) discusses the importance of almsgiving in several major world religions. Although the definition specifies the word is used "in historical contexts", it is still fairly widely known today.

However, as the definition says, this word includes both money and food, rather than food alone. And, in fact, I'd guess that most English speakers will interpret it to mean giving of money specifically, if they encounter it without further explanation. To avoid this, you might use the phrase "giving food as alms", particularly on the first time you mention it.

Answer (score -1):

For the activity, I can't think of any short word, though perhaps those in the field have a technical phrase. If someone said "food offering," I would think they were talking about something religious. If they said "food handouts," yes, it would be understood, but "handouts" has a negative connotation in many places. I don't think people would use it in a neutral sense.

"Charitable food distribution" is completely correct, but it is a long phrase, and I doubt that it is an idiom. I have heard people talk about "hunger relief," but that's more a *consequence* of the activity than the activity itself. You could also talk about "food assistance," but at least in the US that seems to be more used for government programs.

But for the organization that does the activity, you could choose from a few phrases.

[*Food bank* or *food pantry*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/food%20bank) may be what you are looking for:

> A usually non-profit organization that collects donated food and distributes it to people in need.

Some people also use [*soup kitchen*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soup%20kitchen).

> An establishment dispensing minimum dietary essentials (such as soup and bread) to the needy.

Comment: Sorry sir, my question is about the act of giving away of food free of cost, not about any such organizations.

Comment: @mahmud - You would probably be best off going with "charitable food distribution," I think. Or, if you have a word in another language that you would like to use, you could define it and just use it instead.